# How do I pass ``...`` to a new environment in R?

Tags: r

My ultimate goal is to be able to have a function that:

- operates on a function and returns a function
- The return function creates a new environment with .GlobalEnv as its parent and,
- evaluates the argument function inside the new environment.

It would work something like this:

```
# Create an object that doesn't exist in the new.env
iris2 <- iris
model <- in_new_env(lm)(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris2)
```

The reason I want to do this is that I often have applications where I want to generate a model/ggplot inside a function that contains large items that aren't directly used in the model/ggplot call. Because these objects carry around their calling environment, the objects end up being very large when saved, or moved back from a parallel cluster.

My start attempt is:

```
in_new_env <- function(.f){
  function(...) {
    env <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
    # This doesn't seem to actually export the ... to env
    assign("...", ..., envir = env)
    env$.f <- .f
    with(env, .f(...))
    # Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : '...' used in an incorrect context
  }
}
```

This would work if I was able to export the `...` to `env`. How do I do this? Is it possible? Do you suggestions for an alternative strategy for `in_new_env`?

This would then be a convenient wrapper for the solution suggested by Bill Dunlap [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Model-object-when-generated-in-a-function-saves-entire-environment-when-saved-td4723192.html).

Comment: You might want to look at the recently announced `ggghost` package which appears to be setting its task as doing something like this (at least as I understand it) for ggplot2 function chains. (I have no experience with it.) Specifically thinking that `summary.ggghost`, described as  "List the Calls Contained in a ggghost Object" might satisfy the requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `...` really isn't a variable itself so you can't really assign to it. If I think I understand what you are trying to do, you can use something like `list(...)` to evaluate all the parameters passed to a function and store them in a list. Then you can use `do.call()` to pass that list of parameters to another function and evaluate that in a different environment with `evalq`. I think this does what you want...

```
in_new_env <- function(.f){
  function(...) {
    params <- list(...)
    env <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
    assign(".params.", params, envir = env)
    env$.f <- .f
    evalq(do.call(".f", .params.), envir=env)

  }
}

iris2 <- iris
model <- in_new_env(lm)(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris2)
```

Of course the call to the object is a bit off in that it remembers the `.f` function name but it wasn't clear to me what your plan for that was with your proposed function.

Comment: I think you meant to say that `"..."` is not the `name` of `...`

Comment: This certainly answers my question. Thanks! Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. I still get the problem that the formula object ``Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width`` carries around the unnecessary parts of the function environment.

Comment: @42- Well, I think my point was there's no way to assign to `...` and have it "work" inside a function. The symbol `...` has a special mode so it doesn't really act like a "regular" variable. I'd be curious if you have an example where it does.

Comment: @kennyB you can use `environment()<-` to change the environment of a formula. Maybe add in `params <- lapply(params, function(x) {if (inherits("x","formula")) {environment(x)<-env}; x})`

Comment: I didn't disagree with what you did or with the statement that you cannot assign to `...` without a function call, but I thought that we should be explicitly saying one cannot do: `assign("...", ..., )` because `...` has no name in the sense that R uses the term `name` or `symbol`.

Comment: I've tried all of this and I'm still getting the memory problem... I will ask another question because now I'm very confused as to exactly what is causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, i'm not sure. Bill Dunlap's answer really addressed using `subset=` which you don't appear to be doing at all. Or at least this method isn't doing anything special with that parameter.

Comment: Ah, ok @42-. Make sense. I guess i kind of just skipped over the problems of the proposed function and just talked about my solution. Good point.