# How do I write an adverb function that returns a function evaluated in a different environement?

Tags: r

This is closely related to the question: [How do I pass ``...`` to a new environment in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881125/how-do-i-pass-to-a-new-environment-in-r/38881773?noredirect=1#comment65125349_38881773)

And the thread [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Model-object-when-generated-in-a-function-saves-entire-environment-when-saved-td4723192.html).

My ultimate goal is to be able to have a function that:

- operates on a function and returns a function
- The return function creates a new environment with .GlobalEnv as its parent
- it evaluates the argument function inside the new environment.
- And it solves the save-size problem described below.

The save size problem is the problem that lm (and other, for example ggplot) objects save their calling environments, which can often contain irrelevant information. The goal is to have a convenient wrapper that fixes this problem. To demonstrate:

```
saveSize <- function (object) {
  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".RData")
  on.exit(unlink(tf))
  save(object, file = tf)
  file.size(tf)
}

tmp_fun <- function(){
  iris_big <- lapply(1:10000, function(x) iris)
  lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
}

out <- tmp_fun()
object.size(out)
# 48008
saveSize(out)
# 1002448 - Far too large as it contains iris_big.
```

Bill Dunlap proposes this solution which works:

```
tmp_fun_Bill <- function(){
  iris_big <- lapply(1:10000, function(x) iris)
  env <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
  with(env, lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris))
}

out <- tmp_fun_Bill()
object.size(out)
# 48008
saveSize(out)
# 4478 - this works!
```

I would like to generalize Bill's approach into one of these functions that return functions (like `purrr::safely`).

My best attempt, with help from @MrFlick:

```
in_new_env <- function(.f){
  function(...) {
    params <- list(...)
    env <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
    # Change the environment of any formula objects
    params <- lapply(params, function(x) {if (inherits("x","formula")) {environment(x)<-env}; x})
    assign(".params.", params, envir = env)
    env$.f <- .f
    evalq(do.call(".f", .params.), envir=env)
  }
}

tmp_fun_me <- function(){
  iris_big <- lapply(1:10000, function(x) iris)
  in_new_env(lm)(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
}

out <- tmp_fun_me()
object.size(out)
# 48008
saveSize(out)
# 1002448 - too big again
```

Can someone point out what's going wrong here?

Comment: I had a typo. It should have been `params <- lapply(params, function(x) {if (inherits(x,"formula")) {environment(x)<-env}; x})` but that just seems to be part of the problem. It really comes down to where the formula is created.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is really the that the formula grabs the current environment. Here's a function that will set the environment for the formula to an empty environment and

```
dropenv <- function(x) {
    env <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
    if (inherits(x,"formula")) {
        environment(x)<-env
    }
    x
}

tmp_fun_drop <- function(){
    iris_big <- lapply(1:10000, function(x) iris)
    lm(dropenv(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width), data = iris)
}
```

But this requires evaulating and parsing the formula argument to the `lm()` function. Here's a possible workaround for your desired method calling

```
in_new_env <- function(.f){
  function(formula, ...) {
    formula <- dropenv(formula)
    .f(formula, ...)
  }
}

tmp_fun_drop <- function(){
  iris_big <- lapply(1:10000, function(x) iris)
  in_new_env(lm)(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
}
```

Now the function returned by `in_new_env` assumes that the first parameter will be a formula and will clear out the environment for that formula.